# Can Testcontainers create docker network for me if it does not exist?

Tags: docker, docker-network, testcontainers

Looks like I need a network because I would like to reference one container by hostname from another.

I could also use the `--link` but it is deprecated and can disappear soon. That's why I wonder if Testcontainers can create a docker network for me.

With command line I would just execute `docker network create bridge2` and then I can start containers like this:

```
docker run -it --rm --net=bridge2 --name alpine1 alpine
docker run -it --rm --net=bridge2 --name alpine2 alpine
```

and resolve `nslookup alpine2` from `alpine1` container.

If I try to use default `--net=bridge` network or skip `--net` option (which is actually the same) referencing by name will not work.

Comment: Is docker-compose an option for you?

Comment: @YannicHamann no, because looks like with Testcontaiers compose I can only work with exposed port and won't be able to execute arbitrarily commands for example. There are many limitations with compose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can create networks with TestContainers. We're going to document it soon, but it's as simple as:

First, create a network:

```
@Rule
public Network network = Network.newNetwork();
```

Then, configure your containers to join it:

```
@Rule
public NginxContainer nginx = new NginxContainer<>()
        .withNetwork(network) // <--- Here
        .withNetworkAliases("nginx") // <--- "hostname" of this container
        .withCustomContent(contentFolder.toString());

@Rule
public BrowserWebDriverContainer chrome = new BrowserWebDriverContainer<>()
        .withNetwork(network) // <--- And here
        .withDesiredCapabilities(DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
```

Now Nginx container will be visible to Chrome as "http://nginx/".

The same example in our tests:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/540f5672df90aa5233dde1dde7e8a9bc021c6e88/modules/selenium/src/test/java/org/testcontainers/junit/LinkedContainerTest.java#L27

Comment: Cool, this is exactly what I expected from Testcontainers posting this question :)