# Unable to connect to neo4j testcontainer from another testcontainer in the same network

Tags: docker, neo4j, integration-testing, microservices, testcontainers

There is a nice example of creating Testcontainers in the same network here: [Can Testcontainers create docker network for me if it does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548199/can-testcontainers-create-docker-network-for-me-if-it-does-not-exist)

My environment differs a bit and unfortunately I don't get the connection between both containrs.

Here how my setup looks like:

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.RuleChain;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.springframework.boot.test.util.EnvironmentTestUtils;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.Network;
import org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.Wait;

@ContextConfiguration(initializers = RuleCombination.Initializer.class)
public abstract class RuleCombination {

private static final Integer NEO4j_EXPOSED_PORT = 7687;

private static final Integer MYSERVICE_EXPOSED_PORT = xxxx;

private static Network network = Network.newNetwork();

private static GenericContainer neo4jContainer =
        new GenericContainer("preconfigured-neo4j-container")
                .withExposedPorts(NEO4j_EXPOSED_PORT)
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withNetworkAliases("neo4j")
                .withEnv("NEO4J_dbms_security_auth__enabled", "false")
                .waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort());


static {
    neo4jContainer.start();
}

private static GenericContainer myserviceContainer =
        new GenericContainer("myservice-container")
                .withExposedPorts(MYSERVICE_EXPOSED_PORT)
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withEnv("spring.data.neo4j.uri",
                        "bolt://" + "neo4j" + ":" +
                                neo4jContainer.getMappedPort(NEO4j_EXPOSED_PORT));

static {
    myserviceContainer.start();
}


@Rule
public TestRule containerCombination = RuleChain.outerRule(myserviceContainer).around(neo4jContainer);

public static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        EnvironmentTestUtils.addEnvironment(
            configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment(),   
            "feign.myservice.url: http://" + myserviceContainer.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + myserviceContainer.getMappedPort(MYSERVICE_EXPOSED_PORT));
    }
}
}
```

Wenn I run the test using this configuration, I get the error

```
ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to neo4j:32819
```

Any idea how could I correctly pass the ip of the neo4j container to myservice container?

Answer (score 2):

The error was to use the mapped Neo4j port `neo4jContainer.getMappedPort(NEO4j_EXPOSED_PORT)` in the myserviceContainer instead of the exposed port itself.

Also the @Rule with the RuleChain isn't needed in this case.